# Consulta de meses anteriores SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso de uma ajuda referente a uma Consulta que traga os últimos 5 meses referente ao mês atual, porque eu preciso disso, porque eu preciso consultar o total de produto vendido nos últimos 5 meses, a consulta trás todos os produtos e soma a quantidade vendida por loja. Mas não me lembro de um comando que me permitiu realizar uma consulta vendo apenas os últimos meses.

Uma opção seria pedir ao usuário um período, mas quero usar essa consulta para criar uma view para usar em outro relatório que estou criando, por isso preciso que ele sempre me traga os últimos 5 meses.

De momento meu Sql está dessa forma:

```
select sum(iv.qtde) as "QTDE VENDIDA",
   iv.produto,
   p.descritivo,
   v.empresa
      from vendas v,
           itens_venda iv,
           produtos p
where v.id     = iv.venda
and   p.id     = iv.produto
and   p.status = 1
and v.data_hora between '01/11/2022' and '28/04/2023'
group by  iv.produto,
          p.descritivo,
          v.empresa
order by 4
```

Estou usando a data dessa forma pois não sei como posso fazer para pegar somente os últimos 5 meses.

Comment: use o `add_months`:  `where v.data_hora > add_months(v.data_hora, -5)`

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado. Ajudou muito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisas usar uma date function, como ADD_MONTHS, assim:

```
select sum(iv.qtde) as "QTDE VENDIDA",
   iv.produto,
   p.descritivo,
   v.empresa
      from vendas v,
           itens_venda iv,
           produtos p
where v.id     = iv.venda
and   p.id     = iv.produto
and   p.status = 1
and v.data_hora >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -5)
group by  iv.produto,
          p.descritivo,
          v.empresa
order by 4
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado. Ajudou demais